# Adding a cast to a parameter

Tags: sql, casting

If I have a sql query is it possible for me to add a cast to a dynamic parameter? Here is my sql query:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT MATERIAL.MATERIALID FROM DATA WHERE MATERIAL.MATERIALID = :VALUE "
```

I need to cast `:VALUE` as a double and was just wondering if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MATERIAL.MATERIALID
FROM DATA
WHERE MATERIAL.MATERIALID = cast(:VALUE as float)
```

However, it is a *really, really, really* bad idea to do equality comparisons on floating point representations of numbers.  Two numbers might look the same, but compare differently.  Are you sure you can't do the comparison as an integer?

Comment: Yeah i see what you're saying, it's not returning the correct amount of rows in the table. Would casting it as an int just be `cast(:VALUE as int)` ?

Comment: @bbesase . . . In most databases, yes.  In MySQL, I think it would be `cast(:Value as unsigned)`.